# Properties of function with negative Fourier sine coefficients

Tags: calculus, inequality, fourier-series, laplace-transform

I have* a periodic positive function $f(\tau) = f(\tau + T) > 0$, you can assume it to be as smooth as you want.
I need to prove that the integral

$$ \int_0^T \sin(\frac{2\pi a}{T} \tau)\, {\mathrm e}^{\gamma \tau / 2}\, f(\tau) \; {\mathrm d}\tau $$

is $\leq 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb N$ ($\gamma > 0$ is a constant).
Unfortunately, it is not necessarily true that $\partial_\tau \left( {\mathrm e}^{\gamma \tau / 2}\, f(\tau) \right)$ is positive for all $\tau$, but note that it has to be positive on average because $f$ is periodic and ${\mathrm e}^{\gamma T/2} > 1$.

Except for the exponential factor, this looks like Fourier sine coefficients which have to be negative.
I'd be happy about any suggestions for theorems / reformulations that might help me in the proof.
*I am hoping for an answer like* "the integral is $\leq 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb N$ if $f$ has the property X.

<sub>* $f$ is given by a quite complicated expression, I am hoping to prove the negativity of the integral using only more abstract properties of $f$ / I have not been able to see anything from the explicit expression for $f$. From a lot of numerical experiments I am quite confident that the integral is indeed always negative, but proving this has turned out to be more diffecult than expected...</sub>

Comment: E.g. for $f(\tau)=f(T-\tau)$ the integral is negative.  - But for $f(\tau)=f(T+\tau)$ it can be also positive. With $\int\limits_0^T  \sin(\frac{2\pi a}{T}\tau) e^{\gamma\tau/2}f(\tau)d\tau$
$= \sum\limits_{k=1}^a \int\limits_{\frac{2k-2}{2a}T}^{\frac{2k-1}{2a}T}  \sin(\frac{2\pi a}{T}\tau) e^{\gamma\tau/2}f(\tau)d\tau + \sum\limits_{k=1}^a \int\limits_{\frac{2k-1}{2a}T}^{\frac{2k}{2a}T}  \sin(\frac{2\pi a}{T}\tau) e^{\gamma\tau/2}f(\tau)d\tau  $ $f(x)$ can be defined (perhaps depending on a), that the value of the second (negative) part is smaller than the value of the first (positive) part.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is $\leqslant 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb N$ if ${\mathrm e}^{\gamma \tau / 2}\, f(\tau) $ is not-decreasing.
To "prove" that consider the integral as [Darboux Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral).